# How do I get a sum of negative numbers in an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, sum

I want to input 2 numbers and calculate the total of the numbers in between the 2 numbers and it self. 
eg (1,3) 1+2+3 = 6

I have tried the code below, this works with 2 positives however this does not add up positive + negative and returns 0 everytime

```
def get_sum(a,b)
 if a > b || a < b 
  num_array = (a..b).to_a.sum
  puts num_array
  else 
  puts a
 end
end

get_sum(2,-3)
```

expected -3 instead returns 0

Comment: Something like: `Range.new(*[a, b].sort).sum`.

Comment: Some points: Use two spaces for indentation; the `else` should be aligned with the corresponding `if`; don't use `puts` inside of your method. The printing of the result is not the responsibility of the method. Print when calling so `puts get_sum(2, -3)` etc.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. There are numbers between 2 and -3, so the sum *should* be 0, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the sum of an algebraic series.

```
def get_sum(a,b)
  ((a-b).abs+1)*(a+b)/2
end

get_sum( 1,  4)  #=>  10 
get_sum( 4,  1)  #=>  10 
get_sum(-4, -1)  #=> -10 
get_sum(-1, -4)  #=> -10
get_sum(-3,  4)  #=>   4
get_sum( 4, -3)  #=>   4
get_sum(-4,  3)  #=>  -4 
get_sum( 3, -4)  #=>  -4
```

`(a-b).abs+1` is the number of elements in the series.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is reverse the order of the numbers if the end value is greater than the beginning value:

```
a, b = b, a if a > b
```

According to the book "Programming Ruby", the Range object stores the two endpoints of the range and uses the .succ member to generate the intermediate values.

Comment: Which means you can avoid the unnecessary conversion to an array by using `(a..b).inject &:+` once the bounds are properly ordered.  Makes the whole thing a two-liner, and less wasteful of storage.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x..y).to_a.sum
```

where x is the range starting number and y is the last element.
Refer to:
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html

Comment: Why do you convert to an array? Not only does `Range` also have a `sum` method, its method is also optimized for integers, taking only O(1) steps instead of O(n) for the array version.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the complexity involved, but can you please explain how it is O(1)?

Comment: Well, it is simply using the well-known closed-form formula for the sum from x to y.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, mixing up for Ruby 2.6:

```
x, y = 2, -3
[x,y].tap{ |a| a.reverse! if a[0] > a[1] }.then{ |x,y| (x..y).sum }
#=> -3
```